# Displaying non readable DB data into readable format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, class-properties

I have a table that contains a field that only has numbers. What I'm trying to achieve is to represent the actual numbers within an enum and "translate" the numbers into values that is readable.

For example, I have a User table with a field called User Roles. There are 4 kinds of roles: `super admin`, `admin`, `manager`, and `regular user`.

`Super Admin is represented as 0
Admin is represented as 1
Manager is represented as 2
ManagerAdmin is represented by 3 (combination of admin = 1 and Manager = 2)
Regular user is represented as 4`

How can I display `Manager; Admin` when trying to translate from Enum = 3?

> UserModel

`public int UserRoles {get; set;}
public string UserNames {get; set;}
public string UserAddress {get; set;}`

> Enum

```
public enum UserRole
{
  SuperAdmin = 0,
  Admin = 1,
  Manager = 2,
  Regular = 3
  ManagerAdmin = 4
}
```

> C# Code

```
public IEnumerable<User> UserInfo()
{
 var userInfo = context.User.Select(u => new UserModel
 {
   UserRoles = u.Roles, //this is where I want the actual string roles
   UserNames = u.Names,
   UserAddress = u.Address
 }).ToList();
}
```

> > //I was thinking something like this:

```
if(u.Roles == 0)
{
    // project Super Admin
}
else if(u.Roles == 1)
{
    // project Admin
} etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.GetName(typeof(UserRole), enumValue)` would give you the `Rolename` that you are looking for. Here `enumValue` would be 0,1,2,3

```
var userInfo = context.User.Select(u => new UserModel
{
   UserRoles =Enum.GetName(typeof(UserRole), u.Roles) , 
   UserNames = u.Names,
   UserAddress = u.Address
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Do I need to import a namespace for Enum.GetName? I can't seem to be able to use it

Comment: It should be under System namespace

Comment: Sorry to bother you Ashok. What if I have Enum = 3 which represents a combination of both Manager and Admin. How can I display `Manager; Admin` (separated by semi-colon)?

Comment: I do not think it is the right idea or right design to have a additional enum or additional value in the database just to indicate that user has two roles.If a user is both Manager and Admin he should have two rows  (1 and 2) in the database and not 3.So when you query this user you would have an array of roles which can be seperated by a semicolon.